# NSURLErrorDomain Error Code -1005

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6, cs193p

I'm working on the CS193p coursework from Stanford (I'm not a Stanford student I'm just trying to learn), assignment number 5, where we have to get images from Flickr using calls to the Flickr api. I'm only trying to download a list of the pictures and print them out to the console, but I'm getting an NSURLErrorDomain with code -1005. The error message I am printing out is below:

error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1005.)" UserInfo=0x7f9449c83df0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.places.getTopPlacesList&place_type_id=7&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_key=4f9c3155b34836b2ac15318d98b93f3a, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.places.getTopPlacesList&place_type_id=7&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_key=4f9c3155b34836b2ac15318d98b93f3a, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=57, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9449c7fca0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1005.)"}

The Flickr API call is happening in the following method:

```
NSURLSession *urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration]];
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [urlSession downloadTaskWithURL:[FlickrFetcherHelper URLforTopPlaces] completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSArray *topPlaces;
    if (!error) {
        topPlaces = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location] options:0 error:&error] valueForKeyPath:FLICKR_RESULTS_PLACES];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        completionHandler(topPlaces, error);
    });
}];
[downloadTask resume];
```

I'm using xCode 6, not sure if that has anything to do with the problem. The same code was working a couple days ago, and I don't think I changed anything that would mess it up, but it clearly has.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using the iOS8 (iPhone 6 for example) simulator? If so, try changing to iPhone 5s. I was having the same problem and switched my simulator and all worked well again. I tried this after reading the following feedback: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2314

Comment: Every time I faced issues like this, it makes me mad. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to iOS Simulator and do "Reset Content and Settings ..." from top menu.